# Magento Gmail and ZEND

Tags: email, magento-1.8

I'm using this code to send an email in Magento.

```
public function send()
    {
        $config = array('ssl' => 'tls',
        'port' => 587,
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => '[ME]@gmail.com',
        'password' => '[PASS]');

        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')) {
            return $this;
        }

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();

        if (strtolower($this->getType()) == 'html') {
            $mail->setBodyHtml($this->getBody());
        }
        else {
            $mail->setBodyText($this->getBody());
        }

        $mail->setFrom($this->getFromEmail(), $this->getFromName())
            ->addTo($this->getToEmail(), $this->getToName())
            ->setSubject($this->getSubject());
        $mail->send($transport);

        return $this;
    }
```

This works fine, but, the people who receive the email can see that it's sended by: [ME]@gmail.com how can I change this in the Zend mailer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$mail->setFrom($this->getFromEmail(), $this->getFromName())
```

Sets the from email and the name from class methods `getFromEmail` and `getFromName` - which are likely returning your `[me]@gmail.com` address. If this is a core method, this is configurable within the admin panel **System > Config > Sales Emails**:

[image]

If this is custom code, you should fill in your desired values in the setFrom method:

```
$mail->setFrom('[me]@storedomain.com', 'Store Name')
```

Comment: which class to be extend this mail function? by vijay